# Flutter - in_app_purchase plugin - iOS - works in sim but not on device

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

Building an iOS app, _inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(productIds); returns product details in a simulator (ipad, iphone) and everything works. But if I run on a physical iPhone productDetailResponse.productDetails.isEmpty is true and my product ids are in notFoundIDs. Same if I 'flutter build ipa' and try in TestFlight. Using synced StoreKit.storekit.. in_app_purchase: ^3.1.7. Why this may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting all "Agreements, Tax and Banking" bits sorted and "Active" in App Store Connect has fixed it. Things started working the same on the device, simulator and TestFlight as soon as the forms got reviewed and approved.